# QtSerialPort: readAll doesn't yield all data and no new readyRead signal

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm reading from a USB serial port, but sometimes I have the problem, that data gets "stuck".
On received messages, I send new messages and wait again for the answer.

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 on Windows 7 with QtSerialPort in async mode. After a while, my program gets stuck, because I am waiting for an answer indefinitely. (It is kind of a transient bug, but it does happen if you wait long enough).
With the debugger, I was able to see that I have only received the fragment of a message. On further investigation, I can see that QSerialPort has the whole message in its "readChunkBuffer".

This is my "readyRead" handler:

```
void ModuleCommunicator::onReadyRead()
{
if (port->bytesAvailable() > 0) {
    QString msg = QString(port->readAll());
    msgBuffer->append(msg);
    //qDebug() << "onReadyRead: msg: " << msg;

    if (msg.endsWith("\n")) {
        msg = msgBuffer->join("").trimmed();
        msgBuffer->clear();
        msgBuffer->append(msg.split("\r\n"));
    } else {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < msgBuffer->size(); i++) {
        msg = msgBuffer->at(i);

        qDebug() << "MSG: " << msg << endl;

        if (isResponse(msg)) {
            handleMsg(msg);
        }
    }

    msgBuffer->clear();
}
}
```

I also tried "while(port->bytesAvailiable()". But I see only part of the message in msgBuffer, but the whole one in QSerialPorts buffer. Not sure when QSerialPort emits the signal and when it actually sees the whole message.

Maybe this is also some windows driver buffer issue? What puzzles me is that if I kill my application and fire up puTTY and send a newline, I get the rest of the message.
Note that this is likely not an issue of my serial communication "partner", bc. it works via puTTY etc. and I can see the msg in "readChunkBuffer".

Comment: You mean QSerialPort instead of QSerialBuffer? Do the command line async reader and writer examples work for you, including with custom modifications not to be single-shot?

Comment: Where exactly is your code waiting and what is it waiting for?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes, I have corrected my post. I will have to rewrite the example and test them, but as I said, it takes a while for this bug to happen.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The onReadRead method I put in above is the slot for QSerialPorts readyRead signal (as described in my post). When I get a response, I can send the corresponding next message.

Comment: I finally came around to alter the examples. The error also occurs, but I have a problem inspecting the issue more deeply. For some reason, the debugger treats QSerialPort as an incomplete type and I can't see whats going on inside... Anyway, after reading and writing lots of data, I only get half a message and I get stuck. Restarting the application again gives me complete messages.

Comment: I added QtSerialPort compiled from source with Debug flags, so now I can see something in the debugger. The readBuffer seems empty. I get part of the message and nothing more (after a while). With the original application, I once saw data in the readBuffer and connecting with minicom after killing the app gave me the missing fragment of the msg. That doesn't happen with the rewritten example. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac40a8b47fd38e1961a0

I manually stress-tested the device with minicom, but I don't get stuck that way.

Comment: I tried connecting it to a script with socat, but I can't get QSerialPort to work with socat :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the software of the embedded device that the software communicates via serial port. :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be somewhere in your code. Because the readyRead() doesn't guarantee that you will receive the whole message at once; the message can come by parts on following readyRead() calls .

Also I am strained by:

```
QString msg = QString(port->readAll());
msgBuffer->append(msg);
```

why to transform from QByteArray to QString, and then QString to QByteArray twice?

May you provide an debug output  from qDebug() for:

```
void ModuleCommunicator::onReadyRead()
{
    ...
    QByteArray ba = port.readAll();
    qDebug() << ba;
    ...
}
```

when you "stuck"?

Comment: I know that it doesn't guarantee that. Hence the msgBuffer, which I use to hold the partial messages until I get one with the CR_LF at the end. 
There is no double casting: msgBuffer is a QStringList. So I have a list of strings, that I join in the end. (So maybe a simple string would be better, but initialy I thought I might get messeges fused together and would had to split them).
I have tried qDebug, that's the point. The last output gives me an incomplete message, after that, onReadyRead isn't called any more.